# How do I redirect a domain name to a specific web page using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have 2 different urls: mywebsite.com and myotherdomain.com

mywebsite.com is the default URL that goes to my site's homepage. When someone types myotherdomain.com, I'd like it to go to mywebsite.com/other

Is this possible using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `myotherdomain.com` you can use these directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/other/$1
```

This will also append what follows the domain name to `/other/`, e.g.

```
myotherdomain.com/mypath/page
```

will be rewritten to

```
http://mywebsite.com/other/mypath/page
```

By the way, [these Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs) can be helpful.